# TypeScript signature for a recursive Flatten Function

Tags: recursion, typescript

I'm working on building a Typescript .ds file for reactive-coffee (http://yang.github.io/reactive-coffee/api.html), and I'm running into trouble trying to figure out the type signature for the `flatten` function. An example:

```
flatten(rx.array([1, [2, 3], rx.cell(4), rx.array([rx.cell([5, rx.cell(6)])])])) 
// -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
flatten([1, [2, 3], rx.cell(4), rx.array([rx.cell([5, rx.cell(6)])])]) 
// -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

The question I'm running into trouble with is: what is the correct Typescript type signature for xs? So far I've come up with something like this:

```
interface NestableCell<T> extends ObsCellInterface<T | NestableCell<T>> {}

type Flattenable<T> = (
    Array<T| NestableCell<T | Flattenable<T>> | Flattenable<T>> |
    ObsArrayInterface<T | NestableCell<T | Flattenable<T>> | Flattenable<T>>
)

function flatten<T>(xs:Flattenable<T>) => ObsArrayInterface<T>
```

`ObsCellInterface` and `ObsArrayInterface` are typed versions of RC's `ObsCell` and `ObsArray` objects, respectively.

Unfortunately, Typescript does not allow recursive types, only recursive interfaces. And at this point I'm really not sure how to convert that type to an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work, though I haven't yet had time to prove that it satisfies all possible cases:

```
interface NestableCell<T> extends ObsCell<T | NestableCell<T>> {}

interface FlattenableRX<T> extends ObsArray<
    T |
    NestableCell<T | FlattenableJS<T> | FlattenableRX<T>> |
    FlattenableJS<T> |
    FlattenableRX<T>
> {}

interface FlattenableJS<T> extends Array<
    T |
    NestableCell<T | FlattenableJS<T> | FlattenableRX<T>> |
    FlattenableJS<T> |
    FlattenableRX<T>
> {}

export type Flattenable<T> = FlattenableRX<T> | FlattenableJS<T>
```

Using two mutually recursive interfaces appears to avoid the worst complications from having to support both primitive and reactive arrays.

As I said, I cannot yet prove that this works, but it at least seems plausible.